# Query - String Literal Too Long ORA Error

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am working in Cold Fusion 11* and I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long.
```

First off, I received this error and corrected it after looking over several sites by changing my code from:

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
    update paragraphs
    set paragraph_text = #input#
    where  paragraph_id=#rs_d.paragraph_id#
</cfquery>
```

To:

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
    update paragraphs
    set paragraph_text = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CLOB" value=#input#> 
    where paragraph_id=#rs_d.paragraph_id#
</cfquery>
```

That fix worked perfectly. Now I am getting the same error, but instead of using cfquery, I am building the sql query into a string before working with it. So this is how the code looks:

```
sql = "insert into log (LOG_ENTRY_ID, program_id, paragraph_id, action, userid,";
sql = sql & " paragraph_text_old, paragraph_text_new, comment_id, current_program_status, new_program_status)";
sql = sql & " values (1 ," & program_id & ",";
if (paragraph_id neq ""){
    sql = sql & paragraph_id & ",";
}
else{
    sql = sql & " null,";
}
sql = sql & "'" & action & "',";
sql = sql & userid & ", '";
sql = sql & DoubleSingleQuotes(paragraph_text_old) & "','";
sql = sql & DoubleSingleQuotes(paragraph_text_new) & "',";
if (comment_id neq ""){
    sql = sql & comment_id & ",";
}
else{
    sql = sql & " null,";
}
if (current_program_status neq ""){
    sql = sql & "'" & current_program_status & "',";
}
else{
    sql = sql & " null,";
}
if (new_program_status neq ""){
    sql = sql & "'" & new_program_status & "'";
}
else{
    sql = sql & " null";
}       
sql = sql & ")";
   cfstmt(sql);
```

---End function

```
<cffunction name="cfstmt">
    <cfargument name="sql">
    <cfquery name="rs" datasource="#dsn#">
        #PreserveSingleQuotes(sql)#
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

The cause of the error is old_paragraph_text and new_paragraph_text. I was wondering if it is possible to include a cfqueryparam type solution to this problem like in the previous problem/solution I included.  I tried including it straight like the first one but I am getting compilation errors in the code. Any thoughts or tips would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: *tried including it straight like the first one but I am getting compilation errors* Can you post a snippet of the code you tried? It should work fine as long as you are using [`Query` and `addParam()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ffb.html) OR converted the code to cfml/cfquery.

Comment: This is what I tried, once I can run the program again I will post the error that occurred, I might be formatting the statement wrong. I will try to look into adding this in again. @Leigh             sql = sql & <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CLOB" value=DoubleSingleQuotes(paragraph_text_old)> & "','";

Comment: You can't use cfqueryparam as part of a variable like that.  Also, when using query parameters, you don't have to double your single quotes.

Comment: @Chris - As mentioned, `cfqueryparam` can only be used inside of  `cfquery` tags. If you need to embed params in dynamic sql, you must need to use the cfscript versions of those tags instead, ie [`Query` and `addParam()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ffb.html).  The other option is to ditch the construction of a dynamic sql string and convert the whole thing to a cfquery.

Comment: @Leigh, the question is tagged CF9.  I don't think script versions are available in that version.

Comment: @DanBracuk - There should be basic cfscript support in CF9. At least according to the docs above.

Comment: I misspoke earlier, the version is 11. Sorry about that. Also thanks for the input, I will work on either converting to cfquery or using the cfscript version of those tags.

Comment: Ah, okay.  CF11 has more options for cfscript, such as  [`QueryExecute(sql_str, queryParams, queryOptions);`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/queryexecute.html). It is a little less clunky than CF9's Query.cfc :)

Comment: @Leigh  I was reading through the application and realized I missed part of the function. So I added it to the question. A function is called with the sql variable which places it into a cfquery tag. After reading about QueryExcute I am going to try to re-work the function all together so the cfstmt function does not even get called. I'm new to CF and taking over on a project so thanks for being so helpful.

Comment: (Edit) Yes, if at all possible I recommend getting rid of that kind of dynamic sql, since it exposes the database to sql injection. However, before you replace it, search your code base for the 'cfstmt' function to see if that function is used elsewhere in the code. With a name like that, I suspect it may be used for multiple queries. In which case you would need to convert each query, one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for comments)

> wanted to limit the code so instead of determining the null value
>   outside the query, I added the case statements

Honestly, it does not save much, since the code is essentially doing an if/else either way. Except now the work is done on the db side, instead of the app server where it belongs.

Having worked with a lot of legacy apps, I realize they often incorporate what you might euphemistically call "questionable" code ;-) However, you should **never use raw client variables in SQL**. Unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise, always use `cfqueryparam`.

Internally, `cfqueryparam` uses [bind variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). Two of the most important benefits are:

1. Bind variables help protect against [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), by preventing the literal values from being executed as SQL commands. This protects the database from values containing maliciously crafted SQL.
2. For queries executed multiple times, bind variables also boost performance by encouraging the database to reuse execution plans.  Otherwise, the database may choose to generate a new execution plan when the query parameters change, which is costly.

[CFQueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html) also has some other nice features, such as the "null" attribute. It can be used to submit a `null` value when certain conditions are met.

Finally, in terms of best practices, it is also a good idea to fully scope all variables. So for example, if the variables are submitted in the FORM scope, the final query might look *something* like this. (Modify the cfsqltypes as needed.)

```
<cfquery datasource="#variables.dsn#">
  INSERT INTO into log (
    program_id
    , paragraph_id
    , userid
    , action
    , paragraph_text_old
    , paragraph_text_new
)
VALUES 
(
    <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.program_id#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    , <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.paragraph_id#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" null="#NOT IsNumeric(FORM.paragraph_id)#">
    , <cfqueryparam value="#Session.userid#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    , 'Paragraph Updated' 
    , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CLOB" value="#rs_d.paragraph_text#">
    , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CLOB" value="#FORM.input#"> 
)
</cfquery>
```

**NB:** Unless a column has a different default value assigned, `NULL` will be inserted automatically when that column is omitted from the `INSERT` list.

Comment: Thanks for the detail and explanation

Answer (score 1):

I suggest re-arranging your logic to determine `field null` variables which then get used in the null attribute of cfqueryparam.  Something like this:

```
<cfscript>
fieldOneNull = conditionForNull ? true : false;
fieldTwoNull = conditionForNull ? true : false;
etc
</cfscript>

<cfquery>
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
values
(
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_whatever" value="something" null="#fieldOneNull#">
, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_whatever" value="something" null="#fieldTwoNull#">
, etc
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I took a similar route but I wanted to limit the code so instead of determining the null value outside the query, I added the case statements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. Instead of modifying the existing function which is used in different areas of the application, I added a new insert statement in the position where the function was being called to deal with the clobs. To deal with the null fields I used a `case` statement.

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
    insert into log (
        LOG_ENTRY_ID, program_id, paragraph_id, userid, action, paragraph_text_old
       , paragraph_text_new, comment_id, current_program_status, new_program_status
    )
    values (
        null ,#program_id#,(case when #paragraph_id# = '' then null else #paragraph_id# end)
       , #Session.userid# , 'Paragraph Updated'
       , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CLOB" value=#rs_d.paragraph_text#>
       , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CLOB" value=#input#> 
       , null, null , null
    )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Also I tried modifying the existing function, but I kept running into missing commas oracle error. (I used the same statement as used in the answer, but I think the variables might of had to be referenced in a different way or something.